# how to visible false edit commandbutton inside Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working on an asp.net application. In which i have added a commandbutton which is used to edit the row. My Gridview is

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomerPaymentDetails" runat="server" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" OnRowEditing="EditPayment" 
  OnRowUpdating="UpdatePayment" OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEdit"
  CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" Style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;">
  <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
           <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
           <ItemStyle Width="2%" />
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pay Amount">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="lblPayAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pay_Amount")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPayAmount" runat="server" style="width:100%"  Text='<%# Eval("Pay_Amount")%>'></asp:TextBox>
             </EditItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPayAmount" style="width:100%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                                                </FooterTemplate>                                                
        </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkPayNow" runat="server" Text="Pay Now" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="Pay"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Label ID="txtStatus" runat="server" Text="Paid" Style="margin-left: 20px;" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete?')"
        Text="Delete" OnClick="DeletePayment"></asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="AddNewPayment" CommandName="Footer" />
     </FooterTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
</Columns>
 <EmptyDataTemplate>
     <tr>
      <th scope="col">Pay Amount
       </th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPayAmount" runat="server" />
     </td>
     <td>
       <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="AddNewPayment" CommandName="EmptyDataTemplate" />
     </td>
     </tr>
   </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have a Label "lblStatus" which will be either 0 or 1. If its value is 1, then i want to visible false the Update and edit commandbutton of that specific row. I have searched a lot but not found any perfect solution. Please help me someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would convert the CommandField to TemplateFields. To do so, you will click on the smart tag in the gridview in design view. What this will do is change the commandfields to linkbuttons, where you can set it to false in the behind code. You will want to give your new linkbuttons proper ID's so you can find them in the behind code. Then you will create a databound method.. like..

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

   //Code Here to Disable button. I'd use a Foreach loop like this.
   foreach(GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
   {
        Label label = ((Label)gvr.FindControl("label"));
        LinkButton edit = ((LinkButton)gvr.FindControl("edit"));
        if (label.Text == 1)
        {
           edit.Visible = false;
        }
   }       
}
```

Hopefully this puts you in the right direction. I think this should do the trick.

Comment: But when i use this inside TemplateField then the the update CommandButton does not appears which should be automatically appears after clicking the edit. Please Suggest what i should do.

Comment: It should, I have just tested out converting the CommandFields to TemplateFields and I was able to click edit, and both my update and cancel linkbuttons were shown. Are you able to update what your aspx commandfields/templatefields look like now?